# Bash read within a while loop issue

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I'm trying to prompt the user to enter, say either "5" or "10" And then store it as a variable. And if they do not enter either of these two numbers, to keep prompting them until they do. I've tried to run the following code, but it doesn't seem to work.

> read -p 'Please enter your number. (5 or 10) ' num_choice
>
> while (( $num_choice != 5|10))
>
> do
>
> read 'Please enter \"5\" or \"10\"' num_choice
>
> done
>
> echo "You've chosen the number $num_choice"

Also, it seems like the block quotes don't allow me to use single spacing, nor indent I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong. I apologize, I'm rather new to scripting! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `5|10` on the right hand side of a comparator. You have to "distribute" the comparison

```
num_choice=0
while (( num_choice != 5 && num_choice != 10 )) ; do
    read -p 'Please enter your number (5 or 10)' num_choice
done
echo "You've chosen $num_choice"
```

Note that you can still get errors if the user specifies a non-numeric string.